ML Kit can't read some bar codes
So I'm using Google ML Kit to scan QR Barcodes with Jetpack Compose.
Here is the implementation of the PreviewView
@Composable
fun preview() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val cameraController = remember { LifecycleCameraController(context) }


    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { _ ->
            PreviewView(context).apply {
                layoutParams = LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
                scaleType = FILL_START
                implementationMode = COMPATIBLE
            }.also {
                cameraController.apply {
                    isPinchToZoomEnabled = false
                    imageAnalysisTargetSize = OutputSize(RATIO_16_9)
                    imageAnalysisBackpressureStrategy = STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST
                    setImageAnalysisAnalyzer(getMainExecutor(context)) { imageProxy ->
                        val scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(
                            BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
                                .setBarcodeFormats(
                                    Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE,
                                    Barcode.FORMAT_AZTEC,
                                    Barcode.FORMAT_DATA_MATRIX,
                                    Barcode.FORMAT_PDF417
                                )
                                .build()
                        )

                        imageProxy.image?.let { image ->
                            scanner.process(
                                InputImage.fromMediaImage(
                                    image,
                                    imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
                                )
                            )
                                .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                                    barcodes.forEach { barcode ->
//                                        onQrCodeScanned(true, barcode.rawValue.orEmpty())
                                        return@forEach
                                    }
                                }.addOnFailureListener { error ->
//                                    onQrCodeScanned(false, error.localizedMessage.orEmpty())
                                }.addOnCompleteListener {
                                    imageProxy.close()
                                }
                        } ?: imageProxy.close()
                    }
                }

                cameraController.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner)
                it.controller = cameraController
            }
     )
}

Using code like that, it works just fine to most QR codes.
But there's this one QR code that using this implementation, the app can't detect.
It's this image:

Even after zooming extremily close to the picture, the app still can't detect the QR. But I've tried other scanning QR app and online one like https://scanqr.org/#scan . And it can detect the QR

Is there anything I can do to improve the QR detection of ML Kit? Or any configuration I must add?

What's the format of that QR code?

@SudoKoach  It's just plain QR bar code.

Check out this page for the supported formats by ML Kit: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android.

By the way, trying to scan the provided image with https://scanqr.org/ does not work for me. Can you investigage? Maybe the image was recompressed during upload to this question and some important details are now missing. Can you try to provide us with an image that we can use to reproduce the problem?
